# How do I prevent JGrasp from documenting private classes and variables?

Tags: java, javadoc, private

I don't have much knowledge of using javadocs, but I know enough to generate documentation with method and parameter descriptions. However, when I generate the docs, private classes are appearing. I don't want the user to know about them really. How do I prevent JGrasp from documenting private classes and variables?

http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u400/mfgravesjr/javadocs%20screenshot_zpsnzty7qrn.png

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it seems like they will be including an @exclude tag in future versions of Java. So a workaround I discovered is to open the htm produced from generating documentation in notepad. Find the private variables/classes and manually delete them. Hopefully you can read semantic markup as well as you can read Java. lol